# Draw flowchart with clickable node in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graph, flowchart

I would like to draw a flowchart in vb.net that node can be clicked. Something like below picture
[image]

I searched on google and heard about Graphviz for VB.net. I also use this nugget but i don't know how to use it because there is no any document for this nugget and is it satisfied my requirement (Draw a flow chart which clickable node like a picture).

Refer this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164156/Using-Graphviz-in-your-project-to-create-graphs-fr but it's seem to be node can't clicked.

I use this Graphviz nugget of vb.net but no idea how to use it. Can anyone have know how to use this nuget or any other idea to achieve it?

I really thanks you so much

[image]

Comment: The web page for the Graphviz NuGet package has a link to the web site which has a link to the documentation. Took me less than a minute to find it. What were you doing?

Comment: Thank for your quick respond @Jmcilhinney, Yes, I see but is graphviz suitable for my purpose. Because I see it only draw the flow chart. BTW, is there any example how to use it